# How to compare 2 values within the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to analyze a table that looks like this:

[image]

The goal is to mark each instance where a customer switches either the product type or the method of purchase. I think the best way to do this is to have some logic that basically says:

IF customer ID = customer ID in following cell AND product type != product type in following cell; this is a switch; then I'd want the same thing for 'method of purchase' resulting in the data frame below:

[image]

Where I could then filter based on switching customers and identify when they switched.

I am python beginner and am trying to automate this process. I am sure this is an easy one, only requiring a couple of lines of basic code but any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend use [mre]. Also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
df = df.sort_values(['Customer ID', 'Date', 'Product Type', 'Method of Purchase'])
df['Product Switch'] = ((df['Customer ID']==df['Customer ID'].shift()) 
                        & (df['Product Type']!=df['Product Type'].shift())
                       ).astype(int)
df['Purchase Switch'] = ((df['Customer ID']==df['Customer ID'].shift()) 
                         & (df['Method of Purchase']!=df['Method of Purchase'].shift())
                        ).astype(int)
df['Any Switch'] = df['Product Switch'] | df['Purchase Switch']
```